# How to escape from a recursive method in ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion

I created a recursive function that tries to parse the information from the parsed list. It's kind of hard to explain, but it's something like

In a parse function that parses either a wikipedia Movie page or an Actor page, starts by parsing a filmography list from a wikipedia actor page -> call the same function on the parsed list -> repeat

I set a global variable that counts the number of iterations, but when I try to break out from the function and move on to the next step by doing,

```
if $counter > 10
    return nil
end
```

but it does not immediately ends since there are still functions to be called left (since it's recursive). I tried to use "abort" but this one just terminated the program instead of moving on to the next one.

Is there a way to immedately stop the recursive run and move on to the next step without aborting the program?

Comment: Please provide the complete implementation of method you have.

Comment: You should guard the recursive call with the counter condition. i.e. `my_recursive_method if $counter <= 10`

Answer (score -4):

A bit hard to answer without more code. But i guess you looking for `next` or `break` to jump out of recursiveness.

`next`

> Jumps to the next iteration of the most internal loop. Terminates execution of a block if called within a block (with yield or call returning nil).

```
for i in 0..5
   if i < 2 then
      next
   end
   puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
end
```

Result:

- Value of local variable is 2
- Value of local variable is 3
- Value of local variable is 4
- Value of local variable is 5

`break`

> Terminates the most internal loop. Terminates a method with an associated block if called within the block (with the method returning nil).

```
for i in 0..5
   if i > 2 then
      break
   end
   puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
end
```

Result:

- Value of local variable is 0
- Value of local variable is 1
- Value of local variable is 2

Comment: Since OP specifically stated recursion, this is not an answer. `next` or `break` will not return you out of a call stack.

Comment: That comment shows me why i didn't posted stuff for years. With all provided informations we have `return`, `abort` and loop escapes with`next` and `break`. Nothing more needed to avoid recursions in any form i guess. At least i try to help and not to blame people with information that not even the OP had provided.

Comment: The question was tagged `recursion`, the phrase "recursive method" was specified in the title, and "recursive" was used multiple times within the post. QED, regardless of its lack of other information the question was unambiguously about recursion, and your post does not address that.